# spark aggregatebykey with collection as zerovalue

Tags: apache-spark, aggregate

I'm working with a rdd of tuples [k, v(date, label)] and I'm trying to get all the distinct labels and the min of date for each keys.

I've ended with this piece of code :

```
aggregateByKey((new DateTime(), new mutable.HashSet[String]()))((acc: (DateTime, mutable.HashSet[String]), v: (DateTime, String)) => (if (acc._1.isBefore(v._1)) acc._1 else v._1, acc._2 + v._2), (acc1: (DateTime, mutable.HashSet[String]), acc2: (DateTime, mutable.HashSet[String])) => (if (acc1._1.isBefore(acc2._1)) acc1._1 else acc2._1, acc1._2 ++ acc2._2))
```

I get an OutOfMemoryError :

```
ERROR ActorSystemImpl: Uncaught fatal error from thread [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19] shutting down ActorSystem [sparkDriver]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at com.google.protobuf_spark.ByteString.copyFrom(ByteString.java:90)
at com.google.protobuf_spark.CodedInputStream.readBytes(CodedInputStream.java:289)
at akka.remote.ContainerFormats$SelectionEnvelope$Builder.mergeFrom(ContainerFormats.java:551)
at akka.remote.ContainerFormats$SelectionEnvelope$Builder.mergeFrom(ContainerFormats.java:349)
at com.google.protobuf_spark.AbstractMessage$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessage.java:300)
at com.google.protobuf_spark.AbstractMessage$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessage.java:238)
at com.google.protobuf_spark.AbstractMessageLite$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessageLite.java:162)
at com.google.protobuf_spark.AbstractMessage$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessage.java:716)
at com.google.protobuf_spark.AbstractMessage$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessage.java:238)
at com.google.protobuf_spark.AbstractMessageLite$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessageLite.java:153)
at com.google.protobuf_spark.AbstractMessage$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessage.java:709)
at akka.remote.ContainerFormats$SelectionEnvelope.parseFrom(ContainerFormats.java:283)
at akka.remote.serialization.MessageContainerSerializer.fromBinary(MessageContainerSerializer.scala:57)
at akka.serialization.Serialization$$anonfun$deserialize$1.apply(Serialization.scala:104)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
at akka.serialization.Serialization.deserialize(Serialization.scala:98)
at akka.remote.MessageSerializer$.deserialize(MessageSerializer.scala:23)
at akka.remote.DefaultMessageDispatcher.payload$lzycompute$1(Endpoint.scala:55)
at akka.remote.DefaultMessageDispatcher.payload$1(Endpoint.scala:55)
at akka.remote.DefaultMessageDispatcher.dispatch(Endpoint.scala:73)
at akka.remote.EndpointReader$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(Endpoint.scala:764)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:498)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:456)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:237)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

It seems that aggregateByKey is not the right choice to output a collection and that groupByKey is more relevant for this task but I would have to pass through the data multiple times.

Is there a way to achieve my goal with the aggregateByKey function ?
What is the difference of implementation between groupByKey and aggregateByKey which can explain that I get an OutOfMemoryError with one and not the other one ? 
Something related to the spill to disk strategy ?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, there are many things going on here, so let's go one by one:

1. groupByKey will just shuffle all data for a key to a single executor, load it into memory and make it available for you to do whatever you want (aggregation or not). This is an immediate cause of possible OutOfMemoryErrors if there is a lot of data associated with any given key (skewed data).
2. aggregateByKey will try to be smarter. Since it knows that is aggregating, it will try to aggregate locally before shuffling anything. The methods and zero-value you provide are serialize to multiple executors in order to accomplish just this. So your aggregation logic will be distributed even for the same key. Only accumulators will be serialized and merged. So overall, this method is significantly better in most cases, but you have to be careful still if (like in this case) the size of the accumulator itself can grow without bounds. Relevant questions: How many strings you expect per key? How big are these strings? How much de-duplication you expect to happen?
3. Another thing you can do is to take this piece of advice from aggregateByKey's documentation:

> To avoid memory allocation, both of these functions are allowed to modify and return their first argument instead of creating a new U.

You seem to have declared your Set to be mutable, but you don't actually mutate it, you are always generating new sets. Here is an example that you can use as a reference:

```
    case class Aggregator(var count: Int, var categs: Set[UUID])
    object Aggregator
    {
       def zero = Aggregator(0, Set[UUID]())
       def addWithLimit(agg: Aggregator, newCategs: Traversable[UUID], limit: Int = 5) =
       {
          for(c <- newCategs)
             if(agg.categs.size <= limit)
                agg.categs += c
          agg
       }

       def addSample(agg: Aggregator, categ: UUID) =
       {
          agg.count += 1
          addWithLimit(agg, List(categ))
          agg
       }

       def merge(agg: Aggregator, other: Aggregator) =
       {
          agg.count += other.count
          addWithLimit(agg, other.categs)
          agg
       }
    }
```

I was doing something similar, but in my case only wanted to keep 5 or so strings for reference, might be an option for you too if you can limit the set of strings to be more manageable. But in any case, note how the same aggregator you receive as the first parameter is the one returned.

4. If nothing works, you still have a chance to solve you issue by reducing the memory requirements of each task, by making them smaller. For this, increase the number of partitions (lots of resources on how to do this).
5. Try small optimizations. For instance, you can probably replace DateTime with a long or even an integer, which usually decreases memory allocation considerably and also makes shuffles faster. As a side note, be careful with the granularity of your keys, if you have one key per millisecond, there is a good chance you will not be aggregating much! But that is unrelated to your memory issue.

Hope it helps!